# Выборка из mysql , не зная какое поле удовлетворяет условию

Tags: php, mysql

Здравствуйте! Есть таблица friends, поля в ней: id,user_1,user_2. user_1 Это пользователь который предложил дружбу, а user_2 кто согласился. Нужно сделать выборку, которая будет показывать друзей пользователя, но мы не знаем кто пользователь.. инициатор дружбы или тот кто на неё согласился.

Comment: Я вообще логику этой таблицы не понимаю. id это что (или кто)?

И каков у Вас процесс (алгоритм) заполнения этой таблицы?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

На мой взгляд, в вашей таблице не хватает еще одного поля "status". Когда кто-то предлагает дружбу, то в эту таблицу вносится запись. user_1 - это предложивший дружбу, user_2 - тот, кому дружбу предложили и статус - await. Если второй соглашается, то статус меняем на friendship_forever. Тогда и не запутаетесь, ведь user_1 - это всегда будет предлагающий дружбу первым.

P.S. Я тут прикинул, а какая вообще разница - предложил дружбу или согласился с предложением? Ведь в любом случае, два человека становятся дружбанами и соответственно, что нужно в списке друзей показывать всех.

Comment: Мне нужно вывести его друзей, а если я буду организовывать цикл с двумя полями, то он в своём списке увидит себя

Comment: В общем, вот по [этой ссылочке](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/29e3a/7/0), набросал вам рабочий пример.

Answer (score 1):

```
"select * from friends where user_1=$id or user_2=$id"
```

UPD:

```
"select user_1 from friends where user_2=$id 
 union all 
 select user_2 from friends where user_1=$id"
```

Comment: И как мне организовать цикл с такой выборкой??
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
{
 echo $row['user_1'];
 echo $row['users_2'];
}
Но увы сам юзер, который хочет посмотреть своих друзей, сам окажется в списке, if, тоже не выход, т.к вообще по идее я хочу это всё в массив запихать

Comment: ``union`` будет более быстрым чем ``or``, почти наверное. [UNION ALL vs OR condition in sql server query](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13866221) - вторая часть ответа, где ``company or city``.

Answer (score 0):

Объединить тех, кто ответил на предложения Васи, и тех, на чьи предложения Вася согласился.

```
$query = sprintf(
    'SELECT `user_1` AS userid FROM `friends` WHERE `user_2`=%1$d
     UNION
     SELECT `user_2` AS userid FROM `friends` WHERE `user_1`=%1$d',
    $id
);
```